# ASP.NET Core authentication AddMicrosoftAccount() get value "access_token"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

What I did so far is to follow the tutorial from:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-7.0

In my ASP.NET Core 7 app I added Microsoft authentication as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
    {
        microsoftOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
        microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
        microsoftOptions.SaveTokens = true;
    });
```

I can't figure out how to get value to `access_token`, `refresh_token`, `issued` and etc which MS sends in response.

In my opinion access to value tokens should be next:

```
var authenticateResult = someMethod()
var accessToken = authenticateResult.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token");
```

Comment: You're looking for [`GetExternalLoginInfoAsync`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Data/Repositories/AccountRepository.cs#L224)

Comment: A simple call to `ExternalLoginSignInAsync` does everything for you ([code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L643))

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you followed allows you to sign in your app with Microsoft account, and also allows you to [have multiple authentication providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-7.0#multiple-authentication-providers) which allows to sign in with many kinds of account. And this is the authentication process but not the authorization process.

The tutorial requires you to have an Azure AD app to realize the authentication and for Azure AD, it has msal library to do the authentication and authorization. It looks like you are having an asp.net core web app, you only need to follow the tutorial to integrate Azure AD into your web app, then the sign in process and the validation process would be done automatically by the SDK.

The who process should be like: you added authentication scheme into your application, when a request without user identity coming into a view which has `[Authorize]` attribute, the app would redirect to the microsoft sign in page and ask you to sign in the microsoft identity platform using microsoft account like `xxx@xx.onmicrosoft.com`, the identity platform would validate the sign in  and return user information if successed.

Here's microsoft [official samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code?tabs=apptype#web-applications).

```
@using System.Security.Principal
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="navbar-text">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</li>
        <li><a asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a></li>
    </ul>
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

In the sample we would have identity partial view like this which would redirect sign in request to identity platform.

[image]

About the [access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens), firstly, we don't need it when we just want to do a sign in, we need it when having an API protected by API. Secondly, even if we need to validate the access token, the validation is done by the SDK as well, we just need to set up in the configuration and program.cs to ask SDK to check the target claims, like this:

```
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(policies =>
{
    policies.AddPolicy("p-web-api-with-roles-user", p =>
    {
        p.RequireClaim("roles", "Tiny.AccessEndpoint");
        //p.RequireClaim("roles", "Global Administrator");
    });
});
```